# How to deal with Korean character and special symbol in file interpret

Tags: python, character-encoding

Here's my video file name
"[M⧸V] 김예림(림킴) - Confess To You ：： 킹더랜드(King the Land) OST Part.2 [vzH3-8_Y7oo].mp4"

```
import subprocess
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH3-8_Y7oo'
filename = subprocess.getoutput(f'yt-dlp -f 399 {url} --print filename')
print(filename)
```

Here's the output
[MV] () - Confess To You ：： (King the Land) OST Part.2 [vzH3-8_Y7oo].mp4

as can see '/' and Korean character is missing how to solve it?

I try

```
import subprocess
import unicodedata
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH3-8_Y7oo'
filename = subprocess.getoutput(f'yt-dlp -f 399 {url} --print filename')
filename_normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', filename).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
print(filename)
```

but still cannot print the right filename, I found that I could properly print Mandarin character within the file while Korean character cannot

Solved
I add "--encoding utf-8" at the end of link

```
cmd = "yt-dlp -f 399 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH3-8_Y7oo --print filename --encoding utf-8"
videos = RUN(cmd.split(), capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8').stdout
print(videos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *run()* function of the *subprocess* module is the preferred mechanism. You can provide an encoding specification.

Thus:

```
from subprocess import run as RUN

cmd = [
    "yt-dlp",
    "-f",
    "399",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH3-8_Y7oo",
    "--print",
    "filename"
]

print(RUN(cmd, capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8").stdout)
```

...gives this output:

```
[M⧸V] 김예림(림킴) - Confess To You ：： 킹더랜드(King the Land) OST Part.2 [vzH3-8_Y7oo].mp4
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems not work for me I still got UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 25: invalid start byte
None

Comment: @GordonChao Are you saying that you copied my answer **exactly** and it still doesn't work? It works fine for me so must be an environmental issue on your system

Comment: I got the solution I add ''--encoding utf-8'' at the end of cmd, then it works

Comment: `cmd.split()` does not work correctly for nontrivial strings; but why do you not specify `cmd` as a list of tokens in the first place? Or replace `split` with `shlex.split()`

Comment: We can't know what encoding your system is set up to default to or what encoding the tool you use emits or supports. You should accept this answer as it tells you everything we can say based on the information in your question. Going forward, any question about character encoding should include information about your system encoding, especially on Windows; we can't and shouldn't have to guess. See also  [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: @tripleee I wrote cmd like that just for clarity. str.split() works for this particular case and therefore answers the question as posed by OP. However, as my "solution" is clearly not up to standard, I'll delete it - or, at least I would if I could

Comment: The purpose of improvement suggestions is not to dissuade you from answering, but merely nudges to perhaps update your answer. If you don't want to, that's fine too.